# Restricting intervals in random generators? SAS

Tags: sas

I'm trying to create a data step that will pick a weekday of any given month using a ranuni() so that each run turns out a different weekday. However, I can't get it not to pick weekends. :S This is what I have and would appreciate some help.

```
%let start=09/01/2020;
%let end=09/31/2020;

data _null_;
start = input("&start",mmddyy10.);
end = input("&end",mmddyy10.);
interval = end - start+1;
call symput('start',put(start,best.));
call symput('interval',put(interval,best.));
run;


data dates;
      newdate = &start + ranuni(0) * &interval;
      if weekday(newdate) >=2 or weekday(newdate) <= 6 then do;
      Weekday=weekday(newdate);
      output;
      if newdate="" then newdate="Weekend";
      end;
      format newdate date9.;

proc print data=dates;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

What calendar are you using that has Sep 31 ?

Loop until you advance the month to a non weekend day.

Example:

```
%let start=09/01/2020;
%let end=09/30/2020;

data want;
  call streaminit(123);

  do month = input("&start",MMDDYY10.) to input("&end",MMDDYY10.);
    next = intnx('month', month, 1);

    do until (weekday (date) not in (1,7));
      date = intnx('day', month, rand('integer', 0, next-month-1));
    end;

    output;
    month = next;
  end;
  format month date9. date weekdatx.;

  keep month date;
run;
```

Comment: Apologies! I made a typo as it was supposed to be August and not September. However, I need it to output a different weekday every time it runs which is why I think it needs to use ranuni according to my instructor. I got it to work this way in my code but I can't find a way to restrict it to only weekdays. It didn't occur to me that I could another loop inside the loop.

Comment: `rand('integer'` is essentially `ranuni` restricted to a specific integer range.